# IP and Subnet to Start IP End IP

Tags: php, javascript

So I have an IP with a Subnet like: 8.8.8.0/24

How can I convert this to 8.8.8.0 and 8.8.8.255 (actually their ip2long resultants)

In PHP and JavaScript

Comment: I think you mean 8.8.8.0/24 for a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Just to clarify; are you wanting to determine the subnet id and the broadcast address for a given IP address and subnet mask?

Comment: I just want the start and end ips of the range specified by the subnet

Answer (score 8):

I will assume you will also need for other mask like 8,16,...

```
ip="8.8.8.0/24"
```

1. extract each parts `ip_array=ip.match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\/(\d+)/)` //js regex
2. convert to number `ip_num = (ip[1]<<24)+(ip[2]<<16)+(ip[3]<<8)+(+ip[4])` //# 0x08080800
3. `mask=(1<<(32-ip[5]))-1` //# 0xFF
4. `ip_num | mask` will be 0x080808FF which is 8.8.8.255
5. `ip_num & (0xffffffff ^ mask)` will be 0x08080800 which is 8.8.8.0
6. you need to convert `ip_num` back to ip string back

Answer (score 8):

To generate a list of IP addresses from slash notation:

```
$range = "8.8.8.0/24";
$addresses = array();

@list($ip, $len) = explode('/', $range);

if (($min = ip2long($ip)) !== false) {
  $max = ($min | (1<<(32-$len))-1);
  for ($i = $min; $i < $max; $i++)
    $addresses[] = long2ip($i);
}

var_dump($addresses);
```

To check if an IP address falls within a range:

```
$checkip = "8.8.8.154";
$range = "8.8.8.0/24";

@list($ip, $len) = explode('/', $range);

if (($min = ip2long($ip)) !== false && !is_null($len)) {
  $clong = ip2long($checkip);
  $max = ($min | (1<<(32-$len))-1);
  if ($clong > $min && $clong < $max) {
    // ip is in range
  } else {
    // ip is out of range
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just treat each IP like a base-256 number with 4 digits. For example,

```
8.8.8.0   == 8 * 256^3 + 8 * 256^2 + 8 * 256^1 + 0 * 256^0   == 134744064
8.8.8.1   == 8 * 256^3 + 8 * 256^2 + 8 * 256^1 + 1 * 256^0   == 134744065
8.8.8.1   == 8 * 256^3 + 8 * 256^2 + 8 * 256^1 + 2 * 256^0   == 134744066
...
8.8.8.255 == 8 * 256^3 + 8 * 256^2 + 8 * 256^1 + 255 * 256^0 == 134744319
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be sort of what you're getting at. It will determine all IPs in a given range.

```
$ip = '8.8.8.0';
$mask = 24;

$ip_enc = ip2long($ip);
# convert last (32-$mask) bits to zeroes
$curr_ip = $ip_enc | pow(2, (32-$mask)) - pow(2, (32-$mask));
$ips = array();

for ($pos = 0; $pos < pow(2, (32-$mask)); ++$pos) {
    $ips []= long2ip($curr_ip + $pos);
}
```